# Cisco 2520 CGS - IP SLA Failover from FE0/1 to FE0/2 Possible?

Tags: cisco, routing, failover

Have two sites with Cisco 2520 grid switches connected over fibre (OPGW, to be precise).

- Site #1 is the existing site, with a 2520 connected to Site #2 (via fibre). There is an existing 3G backup connection elsewhere in that network (via a 1900 + 3G WIC).
- Site #2 is the new site, solely 2520 switches, and needs a backup 3G connection.

The current plan is to connect a 3G router (i.e. Sierra Raven XE) to a second port on the Site #2 edge switch that terminates the OPGW fibre. Ideally, if there's a comms failure on the Site #2 switch FE0/1 port connected to the OPGW (i.e. damage, contractor bumps a FOBOT, etc) the switch should pick up on this and fail over to the 3G router sitting on FE0/2.

My understanding is that setting up an IP SLA on the Site #2 edge switch that hits (via `icmp-echo`) an IP within Site #1 is the 'simplest' approach here.

e.g.

Site #2 edge switch:

`` ip sla 1
icmp-echo 192.168.x.x`
frequency 5
timeout 500
ip sla schedule 1 life forever start-time now
track 1 ip sla reachability ``

`ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.x.x track 1
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 FastEthernet0/2 20 
! metric of 20 to ensure it only kicks in when track 1 fails`

Site #1 edge switch stays 'as is'.

Have I missed anything here? Can we do this purely with IP switches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the inherent issues with routing to an *ethernet interface* -- which is an arp table muderous case of proxy-arp -- I see no problem. (I'm assuming your ping target is the other switch, not some machine that could be randomly "unreachable")

Comment: Correct, ping target will be the other switch. What potential issues will proxy-arp introduce in this case?

Comment: a) something out on f0/2 will have to answer the ARP request for things that aren't it, b) *every* IP address to which you wish to communicate will have an ARP entry. Unless that switch is a gateway for other machines, (b) won't be such a huge issue. (others have had SERIOUS issues because this config faux pas.)